# Long Delay in Composer installation/update

Tags: php, composer-php

When installing or updating composer packages, sometimes there's a **very** long lag that looks like

```
$ composer.phar update
Loading composer repositories with package information
```

That is, the `Loading composer repositories with package information` message appears to hang for 5 or 10 minutes before proceeding.

What, exactly, on a microlevel, is composer doing when it's "Loading composer repositories with package information"?  Is this network lag?  Processing lag? Both? Neither?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After doing some more digging, I was able to profiles this a little better using the `--profile` and `-vvv` flags

```
composer.phar --profile -vvv update
```

These flags let me pinpoint the exact bit of network latency that caused my problems.